# Spectral sequences to compute Hom's in derived category

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Does anybody have a good reference that lists spectral sequences that may be used to compute Hom sets in derived categories (of coherent sheaves, say)?

Comment: The recent book "Representation Theory: A Homological Algebra Point of View " by Alexander Zimmermann has in chapter 3.9. a section about that.

Comment: Thanks. While that book discusses only one example, i feel the reference there might be of use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two reference sheets for computing Hom sets in derived categories, which you may find useful:

1. [Perverse Sheaves Quick Reference Guide](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~pramod/tc/ps/psqr.pdf) and
2. [Derived Categories Cheat Sheet](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~pramod/tc/14s-7260/dercat.pdf).

Here are two more references:

1. [Applications of Homological Algebra](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~pramod/tc/ps/psln.pdf) and
2. [Derived Categories of Sheaves: A Skimming](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501094).